# How to specify rows and columns of a <textarea > tag using wtforms

Tags: python, wtforms

Constructing a wtforms' TextAreaField is something like this:

```
content = wtf.TextAreaField('Content', id="content-area", validators=[validators.Required()])
```

How can I specify the number of rows and columns associated with this textarea?

Answer (score 28):

You are not supposed to do it in the place where you declare the widget. You have do it in the template. For eg:

```
{{form.content(rows='50',cols='100')}}
```

Need to ensure the rows and cols are specified as a string.

Comment: Me neither. There is some corner case which need resolving.

Comment: I'd recommend turning those ints into strings. I think Jinja2 only takes Strings into it's named variables for the most part.

Comment: I think it's a pretty significant limitation of the library that it doesn't specify a way to define these attributes in python.

Answer (score 15):

Much simpler; use `render_kw` argument when creating the field:

```
port = IntegerField(u"HTTP port", validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(1025, 65535)], render_kw={'class': 'form-control'})
mytextarea = TextAreaField(u"Content", render_kw={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5})
```

And then render the file:

```
{{ field() }}
```

Comment: Best way to do this!

Answer (score 5):

There is a tutorial on Flask by [nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page/). Basically, it works like this:

```
from flask.ext import wtf

class ContactForm(wtf.Form):
    content = wtf.TextAreaField("Content", [validators.Required()])
```

and in your html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.content }}
</form>
```

Instead of specifying the layout in html, you can specify it in your css, for example:

```
form textarea#content {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice work around, but it doesn't specifically answer the question of how you do it purely with Flask/Jinja2.

Answer (score 4):

`{{form.text(cols="35", rows="20")|safe}}` is working

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.notes, rows=5) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to modify the rows and columns via the render_kw tag on the python forms page. When I first saw the definition of this on WTForm's website, I didn't know what it did until seeing other people's examples of using this to modify the class of the form element. So their definition just confused me until I started experimenting with it.

> render_kw (dict) – If provided, a dictionary which provides default keywords that will be given to the widget at render time.
>   - https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html

I used this on my forms page.

```
current_templates_in_library = TextAreaField('current_templates_in_library', render_kw={'rows':'4'})
```

To add multiple tags and values, just separate them with a comma like this.

```
render_kw={'class':'myclass','rows':'4'}
```

Then this was rendered in the HTML. Notice the "rows" attribute there that was added.

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="current_templates_in_library" name="current_templates_in_library" rows="4" style="z-index: auto; position: relative; line-height: 20px; font-size: 14px; transition: none 0s ease 0s; background: transparent !important;">
rhel6
rhel7
win_2012r2
centos7
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, add this macro first.

`_formhelpers.html`:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Import this macro and code in this way. it should work.

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ render_field(form.content,rows=100, cols=100) }}
</form>
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use this replacement widget that is remembering default values for the rendering:

```
import wtforms.widgets.core

class TextArea(wtforms.widgets.core.TextArea):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        for arg in self.kwargs:
            if arg not in kwargs:
                kwargs[arg] = self.kwargs[arg]
        return super(TextArea, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
```

Now you can add this new widget to your Field:

```
content = wtf.TextAreaField(
    'Content',
    id='content-area',
    widget=TextArea(rows=50,cols=100),
    validators=[validators.Required()])
```

You now can render this field without any extra arguments and get a 50x100 textarea.

Answer (score -1):

I looked at the code and found that Field class defines both `__new__` and `__init__`. `__new__` takes a bunch of `*args` and `**kargs`. So, you can just pass `rows=x cols=y` in your TextAreadField creation and it should work. I noticed that wtforms is creating a class called "UnboundField" for such cases, I don't know the implications of that as where this would cause problems, if any. But the next step of creating the TextAreaField are same. (That is control goes to `__init__` call as before.)

Comment: That's what I  thought too, but that doesn't work: "an unexpected keyword argument 'rows'"